# How to look at a .NET project architecture at a glance

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

We are working on an enterprise level .net project, where-in we have a huge code base. We have our own different small frameworks implemented in the project.

While working, many a times it happens that I want to see a particular module's (or it's framework's) class hierarchy at a glance, which seems difficult. I have to drill down in different class files to see the relationships. Which is little difficult to do and takes time.

One way is that, I can create a dummy class.diagram file and drag drop particular class files to check the relationships. But it doesn't work that well.

Is there some other practice being used which I am not aware of ?

Comment: I would look at the design docs for the subsystem involved. If you don't currently *have* design docs, maybe now would be a good time to start writing them. Not everything has to be expressed in code...

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like NDepend? http://www.ndepend.com/features/dependency-graph-matrix-architecture#DependenciesView

Comment: Not really, but this looks to be a paid software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I know of is Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition has Architecture tab (I know 2010 and 2012 also have it, but never used in them), that can be used to generate dependency graph of all projects in a particular solution. That can be used to generate dependencies within the projects.

I have seen it shows dependencies to the class levels.

You can take help of [this Channel9 link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-Toolbox-Dependency-Graphs) to know more about it.

Comment: Yes, this I am aware of. But again, that is a licensed software. We generally don't have VS Ultimate license but only the enterprise one.

Answer (score 0):

I've used .NET Reflector (with various plugins) in the same context.
There's a huge amount of plugins available at https://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/ that ease the task even further.

On the "free" side, you'll probably want to give the following combo a try:
ILSpy (http://ilspy.net/) + AssemblyVisualizer (http://denismarkelov.github.io/AssemblyVisualizer/)

Note: all of the above is used to view the assembly's hierachy, not from a source point of view.

Comment: I am not really asking about how to decompiled and see the IL code. I asking about how to look a bunch of classes and their relationships at a glance. So that I can have a quick looks at some small framework's working